# How can I use fittext in jQuery to resize text in a div? // Edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, resize

I try to use resize my text by fittext. the div container have the width 200 px to 200 px. The result should be that the text have to fit in the box no matter how the text have 10 or 200 words.

**Edit**: fittext in jQuery didn't works to fit a text about more lines, that my problem.

So I will try to dynamically the font-size about more lines. If I try this, you see me problem. The text can be dynamic:

```
body{
   background-color: rgb(48, 54, 52);   
}   

.parent{
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    clear: both;
}

.child_1
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
}

.child_1
{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: rgb(124, 170, 52);

}

<div>
<div class="parent">

<div class="child_1" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Lorem 
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,         
consectetuer adipiscing elit.</div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(".child_1").fitText(1.1, { minFontSize: 30, maxFontSize: '75px' });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a box with fixed dimensions, putting to much things, obviously will get full, the same goes for what you are trying to do.

You need either to dynamicly resize de font-size or the div width/height.

Comment: So I will try to dynamicly the font-size about more lines. If I try this:

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [FitText documentation](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js). It's as simple as:

```
$("#div_id").fitText();
```

Still, FitText makes its calculations based on the *width* of the container, not the height. It's good if you want to fit the text in *one line*, but not very useful if you want to fit it in a box.

Comment: any idea to fit text about more lines?